# Background video working on Firefox but not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Background video working well on firefox but not in Chrome can anyone tell me the problem? I tried my best to solve this but failed every time. But some time automatically run on chrome and self-stoped.

This is the link to the website.

Comment: for me, Chrome on win 10 it works perfectly. However, on Mac, this is a security feature where autoplay would only work if the video is muted. So even if you don't have audio on the video itself, please mute it with the `mute` attribute (just add it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add mute in **JQuery** for the video to play in **Chrome**

```
<!-- home banner video -->
        <video id="video"  poster="https://briolaundry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bg-main.jpg" autoplay loop>
            <!--<source src=""> -->
            <source src="https://briolaundry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Brio-HomePage-Hero-473358135.webm">
            <source src="https://briolaundry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/home-banner.ogv">
    </video>
```

**JQuery**:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('video');
    element.muted = "muted";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: Add parameters like below

```
<video id="bg_video" playsinline autoplay muted loop controls="controls">
```

Then remove the controls with CSS

```
/* This used to work for the parent element of button divs */
/* But it does not work with newer browsers, the below doesn't hide the play button parent div */

*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* Old shadow dom for play button */

*::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* New shadow dom for play button */

/* This one works! */

*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```